# R extract the n-th lowest value by values of one column, for all the levels of another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
> df
   c1 c2
1   1  b
2   2  a
3   3  a
4   4  a
5   3  a
6   2  b
7   6  a
8   4  b
9   8  b
10  7  a
```

So for i=3, the output should be the 3rd lowest values of "c1" for both levels of "c2"

```
   c1  c2
   3   a
   4   b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different options, one can be `tapply`

```
    > df<-read.table(text="   c1 c2
 1   1  b
 2   2  a
 3   3  a
 4   4  a
 5   3  a
 6   2  b
 7   6  a
 8   4  b
 9   8  b
 10  7  a")
> df
   c1 c2
1   1  b
2   2  a
3   3  a
4   4  a
5   3  a
6   2  b
7   6  a
8   4  b
9   8  b
10  7  a
> tapply(df$c1, df$c2, function(x) sort(x)[3])
a b 
3 4
```

Or, using `plyr` package, you can:

```
> library(plyr)

> ddply(df, .(c2), summarise, c1=sort(c1)[3])
  c2 c1
1  a  3
2  b  4
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially a variation on a theme:

```
aggregate(c1 ~ c2, df, function(x) sort(x)[3])
#   c2 c1
# 1  a  3
# 2  b  4
```

Comment: I always say to myself "you should use more formula in your code" :). +1

Comment: +1 - for speeds, assuming many rows, you can do `sort(x, partial = 3)[3]`

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(df1)
dt[,sort(c1)[3],by=c2]
   c2 V1
1:  b  4
2:  a  3
```

Comment: A key can be used to presort: `setkey(DT,c2,c1); DT[,c1[3],by=c2]`. Including "c2" in the key just ensures that a comes before b in the result.